# Color print background in terminal with Julia

Tags: colors, terminal, julia

Is there any function that lets you color print the background in the terminal?

I found the function [print_with_color](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/stdlib/io-network/#Base.print_with_color) in the documentation, but it only colors the text. Do I have to add ANSI escape sequences to the strings or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Crayons](https://github.com/KristofferC/Crayons.jl) can do that. It adds a method to `print_with_color`:

```
julia> using Crayons

julia> print_with_color(Crayon(background = :red), "hello")
hello
```

And there's a couple of other syntaxes available to do the same and more.  The normal `print` and `println` are also overloaded, but they differ in how much of the output is colored (both give background to the whole line).

Alternatively, there's [AnsiColor](https://github.com/Aerlinger/AnsiColor.jl).